# how to create ref for a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can i create a parent ref for two getAllNumbers() function component?

```
<View>{this.getAllNumbers()}</View>
<View>{this.getAllNumbers()}</View>


getAllNumbers() {
    let itemArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
      itemArr.push(
        <NumberView
          ref={"NumberView" + numberArray[i]}
          key={`rowA${i}`}
        />
      );
    }

    return itemArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage functional callback to create refs for the NumberView component

```
constructor() {
   super()
   this.numberViewRefs = {};
}
...

getAllNumbers() {
    var itemArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
      itemArr.push(
        <NumberView
          ref={(ref) => this.numberViewRefs[i] = ref}
          key={`rowA${i}`}
        />
      );
    }

    return itemArr;
}
```

When you wish to access them you can access them from numberViewRef object  by using the index.

For example:    `this.numberViewRef[i]`

Since you call getAllNumbers twice you need to prefix the ref with a key. Maybe

```
<View>{this.getAllNumbers("first")}</View>
<View>{this.getAllNumbers("second")}</View>
```

and then

```
getAllNumbers(key) {
    var itemArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
      itemArr.push(
        <NumberView
          ref={(ref) => this.numberViewRefs[`${key}${i}`] = ref}
          key={`rowA${i}`}
        />
      );
    }

    return itemArr;
}
```

and ref it like

`this.numberViewRefs[`${key}${i}`]` or `this.numberViewRefs[`first${i}`]`

Comment: mmm....i have edited my question. I have to call the getAllNumbers() function component twice and how can ref to each other component?

Comment: i'm getting this error, "Cannot set property 'ref0' of undefined" on page load

Comment: have your set `this.numberViewRef = {};` in constructor

Comment: ohh its a typo, there is an `s` missing `this.numberViewRefs= {};`